# Get Blog's Title and Url inside Blogpost Alternate view In Orchard

Tags: orchardcms

I use `Orchard CMS 1.10.1`. I have an Alternate view for `BlogPost detail display type` in my theme.

Inside this view I need **title** and **url** of the **Blog** that is the parent of this BlogPost, Inside this alternate.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the model of the `BlogPostPart`, [you can see it has a property `BlogPart`](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/blob/dev/src/Orchard.Web/Modules/Orchard.Blogs/Models/BlogPostPart.cs#L20). By using this you can get the title:

```
@using Orchard.Utility.Extensions

@{
    ContentItem contentItem = Model.ContentItem; // Cast to ContentItem
    var blogPostPart = contentItem.As<BlogPostPart>(); // Get BlogPostPart
    var blogPart = blogPostPart.BlogPart; // BlogPart is a property on BlogPostPart

    var blogTitle = blogPart.Name; // Get the name of the blog part
}
```

To get the url of the blog, you can use the blog's [module url helpers](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/blob/dev/src/Orchard.Web/Modules/Orchard.Blogs/Extensions/UrlHelperExtensions.cs#L21):

```
@using Orchard.Blogs.Extensions;
@using Orchard.Blogs.Models;

@{
    var blogPart = (BlogPart)Model.Blog;
}

<a href="@Url.Blog(blogPart)">@blogPart.Name</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I have an comilation error in runtime using this code. " 'Orchard.ContentManagement.ContentItem' does not contain a definition for 'As'"

Comment: You'll have to add a using for that in your view: `@using Orchard.Utility.Extensions` But you can also just use the dynamics: `var blogTitle = Model.ContentItem.BlogPostPart.BlogPart.Name;` See updated answer

Comment: I can Access to blog name with this "@Model.Blog.Name" in the Blogpost Alternate. Real problem is how to access Url Of the Blog